# Copy Data Frm Multiple .xlsx files&Paste in Destination .xlsm Files That Are In Diff Folders Python

Tags: python, copy, openpyxl

This is follow up to a previous question, I am trying to copy data From multiple .xlsx files and paste in multiple corresponding destination .xlsm files that are in different sub folders. eg copy data from ABC_Report.xlsx and paste in existing file ABC_2023.xlsm, copy data from DEF_Report.xlsx and paste in existing file DEF_2023.xlsm where is ABC_2023.xslm is in a sub folder 'C:/folderpath/ABC/' and DEF_2023.xlsm is in another sub folder 'C:/folderpath/DEF/'. So far I have a code that does this but only when all destination files are in one folder. My source files are all in one folder which is great, the problem I have is that my destination files are in different individual sub folders

Source Files [image: source files]

[destination files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7g37.png)

```
import os
from glob import glob
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook


def copy_data(src_file: str, dst_file: str) -> None:
  # open files
  ws_src = load_workbook(src_file)["src sheet"]
  wb_dst = load_workbook(dst_file, keep_vba=True)
  ws_dst = wb_dst["dest sheet"]

  # configuration
 start_row_src = 2       
 start_row_dst = 10      
 rows2copy = 100000

# copy data from src_file to dst_file
input_offset = start_row_dst - start_row_src
for i in range(start_row_src, rows2copy):
    ws_dst[f"A{i}"].value = ws_src[f"A{i + input_offset}"].value
    ws_dst[f"B{i}"].value = ws_src[f"B{i + input_offset}"].value

# files directories
src_dir_path = "C:/Users/me/Documents/Mysourcefolder/"
dst_dir_path = "C:/Users/me/Documents/Mydestinationfolder/"

# iterate over all excel files found in source path
workbooks = list(Path(src_dir_path).glob("*.xlsx")) 
for src in workbooks:
    #print(src)
    dst = dst_dir_path + os.path.basename(src).replace("_Report.xlsx", "_2023.xlsm")
    copy_data(src, dst)
```

The code above works perfect if all my destination files are in one folder, doesn't work when they are all in different subfolders, how do I factor in the destination files subfolders into my code? PS: its 40 source files, 40 destination files each in 40 subfolders the subfolders look like this
"C:/Users/me/Documents/Mydestinationfolder/ABC/"
"C:/Users/me/Documents/Mydestinationfolder/DEF/"

Comment: Why do you use `os.path` instead of `pathlib` ? It is the more modern way of handling system paths and directories?

Comment: @MaKaNu I am new to python so just using whatever works lol I am open to doing it better

Comment: Thats fine maybe the most important feature of `pathlib` is not necessary for a windows project: unified pathnaming for all platforms. But in my opinion the package allow much cleaner code about paths. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). Actually the second entry about Basic use explains subdirectories and might help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase it will help someone out there, I figured out how to get the code to copy data from source files in one folder and paste into destinations files that are in different individual sub folders, see below:

```
import os
from glob import glob
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def copy_data(src_file: str, dst_file: str) -> None:
# open files
  ws_src = load_workbook(src_file)["src sheet"]
  wb_dst = load_workbook(dst_file, keep_vba=True)
  ws_dst = wb_dst["dest sheet"]

  # configuration
  start_row_src = 2       
  start_row_dst = 10      
  rows2copy = 100000

  # copy data from src_file to dst_file
   input_offset = start_row_dst - start_row_src
   for i in range(start_row_src, rows2copy):
   ws_dst[f"A{i}"].value = ws_src[f"A{i + input_offset}"].value
   ws_dst[f"B{i}"].value = ws_src[f"B{i + input_offset}"].value
   
      # save the modifications
      wb_dst.save(dst_file)

 
   # Source filepath
    src_dir_path = "C:/users/me/sourcefolder/"

   # iterate over all excel files found in source path
    workbooks = list(Path(src_dir_path).glob("*.xlsx")) 
    for src in workbooks:
    #Dynamically set your dest_dir_path variable using {} and .format()
    dst_dir_path = "C:/Users/me/destfolder/{f}/".format(f= 
    (os.path.basename(src).replace("_Report.xlsx", "")))
    dst = dst_dir_path + os.path.basename(src).replace("_Report.xlsx", 
     "_2023.xlsm")
    copy_data(src, dst)
```

The code above will copy data from your source files and paste in corresponding destination files that are inside individual sub folders